# Where does standard output go when I run lighttpd + fastcgi + web.py as a daemon?

Tags: centos, fastcgi, lighttpd, web.py

I'm running lighttpd as a daemon with fastcgi and web.py on CentOS using:

```
service lighttpd start
```

which works. My site loads. But now the output from web.py (i.e. any exceptions, a log of requests, etc.) is nowhere to be found. Where does stdout go?

I've looked in /var/log/lighttpd/ at access.log and error.log, and neither holds the output from web.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK **stdout** from fastcgi processes in lighttpd is simply **ignored**.

If you want get **stderr** output from fastcgi process you can use `server.breakagelog` option from http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modcgi:

```
server.breakagelog = "/var/log/lighttpd/breakage.log"
```

But this is raw stderr output without event time or source.

I suggest to use web.py or Python logging facilities and log to file.